# Тире и двоеточие в БСП

Tags: пунктуация

Концерн поставил арматуру на сумму в десятки миллионов евро для нужд станции — всего 6 580 задвижек, запорных и обратных клапанов, а также другие типы арматуры.

Правильно ли я рассуждаю, что здесь можно поставить тире, так как это БСП и можно перед второй частью добавить слово "это", и в данном случае вторая часть имеет присоединительное значение? Можно ли здесь поставить двоеточие и как аргументировать? Ведь "а именно" тоже можно добавить. Все время путаюсь в этих правилах...

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания поставлены верно, но это не БСП, а  простое предложение с обособлением: Концерн поставил арматуру - (приложение), а также другие типы арматур.

ПРАВИЛО

1) Обособление приложений, стоящих в середине и в конце предложения, с помощью тире делается в следующих случаях: А) если приложение имеет ДОБАВОЧНОЕ ИЛИ УТОЧНЯЮЩЕЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ (можно вставить союзы ТО ЕСТЬ, А ИМЕННО);   б) если приложение является распространенным или осложненным (однородный ряд приложений, обособленные обороты, отнесённые к приложению).

2) Одно (а не два) тире ставится, если за  приложением в соответствии со структурой предложения СЛЕДУЕТ ЗАПЯТАЯ.  В этом случае считается, что второе тире «поглощается» запятой. Тогда приложение  встраивается в общую структуру предложения.

Comment: Да, действительно не БСП... чего-то я совсем. Но я думала,что "арматуру" здесь является обобщающим словом, поэтому и засомневалась насчет двоеточия.

Comment: А вообще-то "другие типы арматур",скорее всего, ВХОДЯТ в обособленное приложение. Тогда грамматику можно рассматривать различным образом: обособленное приложение в конце предложения или предложение с обобщающим словом.   В этом случае "арматуру" можно считать обобщающим словом, а однородные члены соединены союзом А ТАКЖЕ. Знаки препинания остаются теми же.